# Import external URL content without an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

I am working on a project for a client who would like their own dynamic latest news feed embedded on to the right hand side of our site. It's a fairly custom module with videos and links, not just RSS or Twitter.

The client has uploaded this content on to their servers as a page specially for us to grab,  and have provided us with the URL.

I could embed the content using an iFrame, but they haven't got target="_parent" in their links, so if a link is clicked the new content is loaded within the iframe which isn't what we want. We want it to open in a new tab. We can't change their content or ask them to for 2 weeks unfortunately - which will be too late! To make it even more annoying, we're not on the same domain.

Our system is build on asp.net which I have no knowledge of (I'm more PHP!). It's also worth mentioning that I am a front-end developer in this role and can't access or modify any asp.net code.

I have tried using jQuery .load() without success. Being a bit of a newbie I am unsure of the correct way to go about this, or if it's even possible at all using front-end technologies?

It seems that similar questions to mine are all old and dated so it would be good to get the latest and best approach.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you pull in their content with `.load()`, it has a callback function for when it is completed. Simply loop through all of the `<a>` links in that section and change their `target=` to open in a new tab!

`css: target-new: tab ! important` (unfortunately this is only css3 compatible)

Answer (score 0):

If you can make sure that the `<head>` in the page being loaded contains:

```
<base target="_blank" />
```

Then all the links will open in a new window. If you cannot make sure that the pages contain that in their `<head>`, then an option would be to download the page data via a server-side HTTP request, and add that tag manually before embedding the page into your box. If you don't want to do any server-side work, you might as well do it client-side. Here's a simplified version of how that can be done:

```
$.get("http://exampleurl.com/", function (data) {
    var pos = data.indexOf("<head>");
    if(pos == -1) {
        //pretty impossible
        return;
    }
    data = data.substr(0, pos + 5) + '<base target="_blank" />' + data.substr(pos + 6, data.length - (pos + 6));
    //display data
});
```

Comment: "We can't change their content" :-(

Answer (score 0):

With **jQuery .load()** you would need to extract all the JS code on your page and make it target this part, as it will only load DOM elements. It's a bit tricky but after changing a few things and paths you can get it work.

Another, maybe easier way, but it will work only **if you are on the same domain** :

```
$("#iFrame").contents().find("a").on("click",function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    // then use the href to virtualy create a link click event :-)
});
```